# How to alter instruction variables in LLVM IR?

Tags: c, llvm

The equivalent IR of `a[1]` is

```
%0 = load i32, i32* getelementptr inbounds ([100 x i32], [100 x i32]* @a, i32 0, i64 1), align 4
```

In this example, I need to change `a[1]` to `*(a + 100 + 1)` via a transformation pass.

In general, while iterating over instructions how to

- First identity all the memory reads - what APIs must I use?
- How to update or my constant 100 addition to all of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say you have an `Instruction *I`. To check if it is a `load` you can use LLVM's `dyn_cast`:

```
if (LoadInst *LoadI = dyn_cast<LoadInst>(I)) {
    // We have identified that I is a load instruction, and assigned it to LoadI
    Value *PointerOp = LoadI->getPointerOperand();
```

The `load` instruction simply dereferences a pointer. The value of this pointer is actually calculated by `getelementptr`, an LLVM concept that is notorious for confusing beginners. Take a look here for more details: http://llvm.org/docs/GetElementPtr.html

Now, we can do a similar thing to `PointerOp` to ensure that we are in fact working with a `getelementptr`:

```
    if (GetElementPtrInst *GEPI = dyn_cast<GetElementPtrInst>(PointerOp)) {
        // The load takes a GEP instruction, assigned to GEPI
        ...
    }
}
```

The GEP can take any number of indices. Some indices are performing field offset calculations (choosing a field from a struct), other indices will be performing array indexing. Figure out which of these indices you need to add 100 to (you will need to refer to the type `GEPI->getPointerOperandType()`).

When actually adding the constant 100, be careful that the GEP index may not be constant -- it may be the result of another IR instruction. Hence you need to take that operand and replace it with a new `add` instruction.

The following may be relevant:

- `ConstantInt::get`: http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/classllvm_1_1ConstantInt.html#a9105541412dab869e18b3cceebfff07d
- `BinaryOperator::Create` with the `Instruction::Add` opcode: http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/classllvm_1_1BinaryOperator.html#a02ce9966395063ac501ecbc1623deda4
- `User::setOperand`: http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/classllvm_1_1User.html#a5fa9b8e1842b354f64c1ba6be0a4a17f

It may be useful to note that `Instruction` inherits from `User` in LLVM land, and `User` inherits from `Value`.

Comment: +ChengSun Brilliant explanation! Thanks. I am little confused now about how in LLVM  in need to handle double pointer **a?

Comment: To see what's going on, separate the two dereferences into individual steps. `return **a;` would get turned into two simple `load` instructions. `return (*a)[1];` would be two `load`s, the last of which has a GEP. `return a[1][1];` would be two `load`s, each of which has a GEP.

Comment: One more confusing LLVM jargon -- 'getelementptr inbounds' . Documentation says it is of different constant expression type. Can you please throw some light to understand the concept ?

Comment: Which bit are you confused about? "inbounds" is just a GEP property to assert that the indices are in bounds.